# How can I change the default toolbar in my App?

Tags: android, toolbar

Currently, I'm developing an app but I'm a beginner. I have added some activity layouts but every time I start the app a default toolbar appears. How do I customize this toolbar without "destroying" the implemented layouts?

**toolbar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_logo"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:foregroundGravity="center"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**MainActivity.java (extends RxAppCompatActivity)**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
```

The toolbar variable is always null - why?

Comment: because it's not part of activity_main.xml

Comment: the toolbar has to be declared inside `activity_main.xml` in this case (the same layout id you pass as argument to `setContentView`

Comment: Can we see your activity_main.xml?

Comment: I declared the toolbar inside the activity_main.xml but when I start the app it crashes at the line `setSupportActionBar(toolbar);`

Comment: What's the crash you're getting? And what theme are you using? Is it something with `NoActionBar` at the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the XML code in your activity XML file. Since the  tag is not included in your activity_main.xml, you will always get a NullPointerException when you try to find it by id.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.screens.MainActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_logo"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:foregroundGravity="center"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<!--Rest of your XML-->


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Note: I used ConstraintLayout just for example, you can use any layout you like (although ConstraintLayout is pretty awesome!)

By the way, since you are using ButterKnife, you can easily bind the view with @BindView(R.id.my_toolbar), instead of using findViewById().